# JavaFX: Multiple selectors modifying the same property

Tags: java, css, javafx, javafx-8, javafx-css

I have a stylesheet like this:

```
*
{
    -fx-font-size: 15px;
}

.title
{
    -fx-font-size: 20px;
}
```

I had thought that since `*` is more generic than `.title`, then the `-fx-font-size` defined in `.title` would have precedence over it, but I'm wrong. No matter what font size I changed it to in `.title`, that title label is still rendered at `15px`. When I removed the `*` block, the title label would correctly reflect the size defined in `.title`.

Is there anything wrong with my approach? I'm just trying to set a "global" look and feel, while giving specific nodes the flexibility to adjust it when that node needs a more customized look.

### Edit

It seems like this problem is only visible for font related CSS properties. I have tried changing `-fx-font-size` in my example to `-fx-border-color`, and it seems to work according to normal CSS standard.

It seems like there is something weird with the font properties.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You assign the font size for every node.

For `Label`s (and similar elements) though the text is not displayed by the `Node` itself, but by a descendant node. Normally that node would inherit the `-fx-font-size` property from the `Label`, but since you assign that property for every single node, it's assigned for this descendant itself and therefore the value from the parent is not used.

To fix this assign the new size for descendants of the node with class `title`:

```css
* {
    -fx-font-size: 15px;
}

.title * {
    -fx-font-size: 20px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `!important`:

```
.title{
    -fx-font-size: 20px !important;
}
```

or even better if you have only one element with ID:

```
#title{
   -fx-font-size: 20px !important;
}
```

From https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html on the paragraph:

**Scene, Parent and SubScene Stylesheets**

---

> CSS styles can come from style sheets or inline styles. Style sheets
>   are loaded from the URLs specified in the stylesheets variable of the
>   Scene object. If the scene graph contains a Control, a default user
>   agent style sheet is loaded. Inline styles are specified via the Node
>   setStyle API. Inline styles are analogous to the style="..." attribute
>   of an HTML element. Styles loaded from a Scene's style sheets take
>   precedence over rules from the user agent style sheet. Inline styles
>   take  precedence over styles originating elsewhere. The precedence
>   order of style rules can be modified using "!important" in a style
>   declaration.

---

**Priorities of Styles for a Node**

The JavaFX runtime uses the following priority rules to set the visual properties of a node. The source 
with a higher priority that has a value for a property is used:

> • Inline style (the highest priority)
>
> •Parent style sheets
>
> •Scene style sheets
>
> •Values set in the code using JavaFX API
>
> •User agent style sheets (the lowest priority)

The style sheet added to the parent of a node is given higher priority than the style sheets added to the scene. This enables developers to have custom styles for different branches of the scene graph.

Comment: @Jai Strange ... it should work... Have you added anywhere inline css using Java Code?

Comment: @Jai Edited the code with important notes . If you have used inline style you may have a problem.